# slideDown only clicked element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some menu in my website with same element , i want to use slideDown in jQuery to slidedown only clicked menu

but now when i clicked one menu all menu get slidedown

HTML

```
        <div id="sidebar-right" >



                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                        <span class="sidebar-post">Last Posts</span>
                                <span class="sidebar-post-slide">+</span>

                               <div style="margin-top:-35px"></div>
                               <div class="sidebar-text">
Some content
                            </div>
                </div>
                <!-- S2 -->
                                <div class="sidebar-menu">
                        <span class="sidebar-post">Last Comments</span>
                                <span class="sidebar-post-slide">+</span>

                      <div class="sidebar-text">          
Some content
                        </div>
                </div>
                <!-- End S2 -->

         </div>
```

and jQuery side

```
$(function() {
$('.sidebar-post-slide').click(function () {
if ( $('.sidebar-text').is( ":hidden" ) ) {
$('.sidebar-text').slideDown(800);
} else {
$('.sidebar-text').hide(800);
}
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slidedown the sibling `sidebar-text` element, not all `sidebar-text` elements

```
$(function() {
    $('.sidebar-post-slide').click(function () {
        //find the sibling sidebar-text element and complete any queued animations
        var $stext = $(this).siblings('.sidebar-text').stop(true, true);
        if ( $stext.is( ":hidden" ) ) {
            $stext.slideDown(800);
        } else {
            $stext.hide(800);
        }
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fBbum/)

Comment: Thank you , it works fine , but i have a question , can i change `<span class="sidebar-post-slide">+</span> ` to `<span class="sidebar-post-slide">-</span>`
when it get hidden ?

Comment: Thankyou , but it seem it works after twice click ( it's not working fine at first click , and it not change )
who can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the method [closest()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_closest.asp). But in your case Arun's anwser is better.